# two unrelated models in one serializer django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have tried a few different ways to include two unrelated models in one serializer to use in DRF api response. This is the latest of tries below, which doesn't work. I'm trying to include those two values (enable_hourly_rate / vacancy_number) from Tenant model which are under TenantAppUnitExpandedSerializer to TenantAppUnitSerializer. How to do this the proper way?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Code so far:

```
class TenantAppUnitExpandedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tenant
        fields = (
            'enable_hourly_rate',
            'vacancy_number',
        )

class TenantAppUnitSerializer(TenantAppUnitExpandedSerializer):

    enable_hourly_rate = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    vacancy_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    
    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = (
            'id',
            'unit_name',
            'city',
            'phone',
            'enable_hourly_rate',
            'vacancy_number'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Include it as a field in the `serializer` you desire to work with.
Then `field_name = ThatParticularSerializer()` which you want to include.

Here is how your serializer should be.

```
class TenantAppUnitSerializer(TenantAppUnitExpandedSerializer):
    tenant_extended_unit = TenantAppUnitExpandedSerializer(many=False) # <-- here
    # similarly you can set many=True if you are expecting multiple instances of it
    enable_hourly_rate = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    vacancy_number = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    
    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = (
            'id',
            'unit_name',
            'city',
            'phone',
            'enable_hourly_rate',
            'vacancy_number',
            'tenant_extended_unit`, # <-- here
        )
```